# Create Regex to only allow numbers and 2 digits after decimal

Tags: html, regex

I have a form and I want to add `clear button` to my `inputs type="number"`

So thought id go down the route of using a `regex` as I don't want to have to create a `button` at the end of the `input` as none of my other `input`s, have this.

The below code I have only allows 'numeric' and one decimal but I need to restrict the number of digits after the decimal which is where I'm failing.

```
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" />
```

I know I need to use `{0,2}` but I have tried the following and but they all still allow 3+ digits after the decimal

```
/[^0-9.{0,2}]/g
/[^0-9.]{0,2}/g
```

[image]

Every other character is not typed in the `input` which I want to keep it as but I don't want a chunk of code using the `keyCode`s.

I am no good with `regex` and struggle to get my head around them.

I have also tried:

```
<input type="search" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(^\d+\.\d{1,2}$, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');" />
```

But this gives
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is to add `.replace(/(\.\d{2}).+/g, '$1');` to the button.

It replaces everything after you input a decimal point and two digits:

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1').replace(/(\.\d{2}).+/g, '$1');" />
```